# Linear Algebra, proving subset is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $W$ be a subset of vector space $V$ over $K$. $\forall \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in W,\alpha \in K, \alpha \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v} \in W$ , show that $W$ is a subspace over $K$. Hence, show that the set of linear combinations
>   $$W = \{\alpha_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + \alpha_2\mathbf{v}_2 +\ldots + \alpha_n\mathbf{v}_n, \mathbf{v}_i \in V, \alpha_i \in K,i = 1, \ldots, n\}$$
>   is a subspace of $V$ over $K$.

I don't understand what $W$ contains? Is $W = \{u,v\}$? or is $W = \operatorname{Span}\{u,v\}$??
Please help, I am new to linear algebra.

Comment: As written,the claim is not true: The empty set is clearly a subset of $V$, and vacuously fulfils the condition put on its elements, but clearly is not a vector space. However that is the only counterexample; if we demand $W$ to be a *non-empty* subset, the claim holds.

Comment: $W$ is just any non-empty subset, formed by any finite or infinite number of vectors. The point of the exercise is to prove that by considering all possible linear combinations with all possible coefficients you get a bigger subset that is closed under linear combinations, that is, a vector subspace.

Comment: I've edited your questions to bring it up to the standards of the site. Please see the links in José's comment to find out how to do this for yourself, for next time. Feel free to press "edit" to see what I've done, and play around with it for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You are not given what $W$ contains. And that is the whole point; you don't *need* to know what exactly $W$ contains, as long as it contains *anything*, and the given condition holds, you *already* can tell that it is a subspace, *even though you don't know what it is.*

Indeed, this is exactly where the power of such theorems comes from: They allow you to make conclusions even if you know *very little* about the set in question.

Also note that $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are quantified, "for all $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ in $W$". That is, the statement is not about two specific, given vectors, but it means that if you draw *any* two vectors from $W$, the condition must hold (including, but not limited to, the case that you select the very same vector twice).

So your task is to prove that *every* non-empty subset $W$ that fulfils the given condition is a subspace of $V$.

(Note that I added “non-empty” to the claim because otherwise the statement you are supposed to prove is *not* true, as the empty set is not a vector space; if the task was actually given as stated, you might want to give that counterexample, and then proceed to prove the statement for non-empty sets).

Answer (score 2):

To check that $W$ is a vector subspace you need to check the 3 following conditions: i) $W$ is non empty (clear if $V$ is non empty), ii)if $\mathbf x \in W$ and $\mathbf y \in W$, then $\mathbf x+\mathbf y \in W$. iii)If $\alpha \in K$, and $\mathbf x \in W$, then $\alpha \mathbf x \in W$

For your second question, you need to check these three conditions again. Again (i) should hold.

For ii) and iii), observe that: for $x_i$ and $y_i$ in $K$, and $v_i$ in $V$, we have:

$(x_1 v_1+...+x_n v_n)+(y_1 v_1+...+y_n v_n)=(x_1+y_1)v_1+...+(x_n+y_n)v_n$
, which is again a linear combination of the $v_i$'s.

Now check that: for $c$ in $K$:

$c(x_1 v_1+...+x_n v_n)=cx_1 v_1+...+cx_n v_n$ is again a linear combination of the $v_i$s.

Comment: The problem statement says for all $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ in $W$, not $V$. Otherwise the task would be trivial: Choose $\alpha=0$, and then observe that for every $\mathbb v\in V$, $\mathbb v\in W$, thus $W=V$, and $V$ is a vector space by assumption.

Comment: Oh damn, I just read the statement properly

Comment: but what should be the arbitrary element of W? to prove closure properties?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question properly, i have modified my answer to avoid any confusion

Comment: how to prove  ii) if x∈W and y∈W, then x+y∈W. iii) If α∈K, and x∈W, then αx∈W, how are we assuming that x and y belong to W?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about a basis for W, we can't recognise what does W contain.

But if we have more information about W and V, for example, let a basis for W to be $\{\underline{u},\underline{v}\}$ and a basis for V to be 
$\{\underline{u},\underline{v},\underline{w},\underline{x}\}$

[image]